# html layout for dynamic content

Tags: html, css

I added web interface for a program's output which looks like this:

```
<body>
<table id="header" approx height is 100px, width is 50% of screen located in the middle>
...
</table>
<div id="programoutput">my program outputs stuff here using Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater</div>
</body>
```

I use css for the div

```
#programoutput{ white-space:pre; }
```

and output from the program might contain very long lines. So, web page should have horizontal scrollbars then. What I want, is to make sure that the #header is always in the middle of the screen (not the body) and the body might become wider then the viewport based on the width of #programoutput.

I almost got it already, but I have some problems: horizontal scroll bar appears in the #programoutput itself not the window. and if height of the output is small (like a few lines in this case) then the horizoncal scroll bar is located in the middle of the window.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't be using tables for formatting.

Comment: Very unrelated. I absolutely don't care for css/html validity. It's basically 10 min question. If I can't get it, I'll leave broken it as is. I was just curious how to do it.

Comment: It has little to do with validity, and everything to do with the fact that CSS and tables barely work together. The fact that they aren't valid anymore has repercussions.

Comment: I didn't know that they do not work together anymore ;) Well, anyways, that thing doesn't have to be a table, it could be a div as well.

Comment: Well, they've never played together very well - just try specifying pixel dimensions of individual <td> and <tr> elements in a table that's width-constrained and you'll see what I mean. Complete nightmare.

Comment: even 10 years ago I didn't use pixel sizes. If it's for layout, then I use em or % only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#header
{
 position:fixed;
 width:50%;
 left:25%;
}
#programoutput
{
 white-space:pre;
 overflow:visible;
}
```

At this point your `table` should be placed in the center of *view port*, and your `div` should be long enough for your `body` to generate scrollbar.

But since the `table` is `position:fixed`, your `div` would "float" over your table. Now you have several options:

**1**. Give your `div` a top position:

```
position:relative;
top:100px; /* you'll have to know your table's height */
```

**2**. Place your `div` at the bottom of the `body` (this seems valid in your code piece):

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```